# Execute file.ps1 on windows-machine1 from rhel-server1 using sshpass, bash & PsExec issues

Tags: linux, powershell, psexec, rhel7, invoke-command

If I had hair I'd be bald again.

I have 2 servers.

**windows01**
**linux01**

On the **windows01** machine I have a **GUI based application** that I need to start from **linux01** server.

The script called **start.ps1** on the windows01 machine looks like this: (It is placed where the executable of both the application and **psexec.exe** is located)

```
if((get-process "TmaApplication" -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq $Null){ 
        echo "TmaApplication not running, attempting to start"
        & .\psexec.exe -accepteula TMA.exe /u "Default User" /c y /p 5003
}

else{ 
    echo "Running"
 }
```

However when I run the following from the **linux01** server I get the following: (For some reason it runs from the linux machine and not simply executing the start.ps1 file located on the **windows01** machine.)

```
[root@linux01]# ./test.sh

TmaApplication not running, attempting to start
.\psexec.exe : The term '.\psexec.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable pr
ogram. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Program Files (x86)\redacted\redacted\redacted 1.0\redacted Application\start.ps1:3 char:9
+         .\psexec.exe -accepteula TMA.exe /u "Default User" /c y /p 50 ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\psexec.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The **content of the test.sh** file is:

```
#!/bin/bash
STP="redacted"
Server="redacted"
User="redacted"
Password="redacted"
TMAVersion="1.0"
PsExecSourceFile="/opt/tools/psexec.exe"
PsExecFileName="psexec.exe"
Test="test.ps1"


sshpass -p $Password ssh -o stricthostkeychecking=no $User@$Server 'powershell -InputFormat None -File "C:/Program Files (x86)/redacted/redacted/redacted '$TMAVersion'/redacted Application/'$Test'"'
```

I'm very very new to this, and I am forced to work with what I have copy pasting and what not.
Everything works fine besides this. **If I run the start.ps1 directly from the windows01 machine by right click "run with powershell"** it does exactly what I want it to do. But I need to execute it from this linux machine.

I have full root/admin control over both the linux and windows environment when it comes to OS level. But I rather limit thirdpard apps. Any non-open source is not an option moving forward im afraid if not released directly from Microsoft or RedHat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to install Powershell 7 on the linux machine? https://github.com/powershell/powershell

Then you can use PSSessions to connect to the windows machine through powershell.

```
$session = New-PSSession -HostName UbuntuVM1 -UserName TestUser
Enter-PSSession $session
```

More info here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-7

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work for me for some reason.

PS /home> $session = New-PSSession -HostName ip -UserName administrator
administrator@ip's password: 
New-PSSession: [ip] The SSH client session has ended with error message: The SSH transport process has abruptly terminated causing this remote session to break.

Configured according to guides, sshd_config etc on windows adding subsystem etc.

Comment: Does Invoke-Command fail also? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7

Try using it without sessions though

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, however due to time restraints I had to ditch the whole setup and run everything on windows instead. Sucks, but the problem had to be fixed. :( I'm marking your answer as answered though, thanks for your assistance.